# parallelize (not symmetric) loops in python

Tags: python, optimization, parallel-processing

The following code is written in python and it works, i.e. returns the expected result. However, it is very slow and I believe that can be optimized.

```
G_tensor = numpy.matlib.identity(N_particles*3,dtype=complex)

for i in range(N_particles):
    for j in range(i, N_particles):
        if i != j:

            #Do lots of things, here is shown an example.
            # However you should not be scared because 
            #it only fills the G_tensor
            R = numpy.linalg.norm(numpy.array(positions[i])-numpy.array(positions[j]))
            rx = numpy.array(positions[i][0])-numpy.array(positions[j][0])
            ry = numpy.array(positions[i][1])-numpy.array(positions[j][1])
            rz = numpy.array(positions[i][2])-numpy.array(positions[j][2])
            krq = (k*R)**2
            pf = -k**2*alpha*numpy.exp(1j*k*R)/(4*math.pi*R)
            a = 1.+(1j*k*R-1.)/(krq)
            b = (3.-3.*1j*k*R-krq)/(krq) 
            G_tensor[3*i+0,3*j+0] = pf*(a + b * (rx*rx)/(R**2))  #Gxx
            G_tensor[3*i+1,3*j+1] = pf*(a + b * (ry*ry)/(R**2))  #Gyy
            G_tensor[3*i+2,3*j+2] = pf*(a + b * (rz*rz)/(R**2))  #Gzz
            G_tensor[3*i+0,3*j+1] = pf*(b * (rx*ry)/(R**2))      #Gxy
            G_tensor[3*i+0,3*j+2] = pf*(b * (rx*rz)/(R**2))      #Gxz
            G_tensor[3*i+1,3*j+0] = pf*(b * (ry*rx)/(R**2))      #Gyx
            G_tensor[3*i+1,3*j+2] = pf*(b * (ry*rz)/(R**2))      #Gyz
            G_tensor[3*i+2,3*j+0] = pf*(b * (rz*rx)/(R**2))      #Gzx
            G_tensor[3*i+2,3*j+1] = pf*(b * (rz*ry)/(R**2))      #Gzy

            G_tensor[3*j+0,3*i+0] = pf*(a + b * (rx*rx)/(R**2))  #Gxx
            G_tensor[3*j+1,3*i+1] = pf*(a + b * (ry*ry)/(R**2))  #Gyy
            G_tensor[3*j+2,3*i+2] = pf*(a + b * (rz*rz)/(R**2))  #Gzz
            G_tensor[3*j+0,3*i+1] = pf*(b * (rx*ry)/(R**2))      #Gxy
            G_tensor[3*j+0,3*i+2] = pf*(b * (rx*rz)/(R**2))      #Gxz
            G_tensor[3*j+1,3*i+0] = pf*(b * (ry*rx)/(R**2))      #Gyx
            G_tensor[3*j+1,3*i+2] = pf*(b * (ry*rz)/(R**2))      #Gyz
            G_tensor[3*j+2,3*i+0] = pf*(b * (rz*rx)/(R**2))      #Gzx
            G_tensor[3*j+2,3*i+1] = pf*(b * (rz*ry)/(R**2))      #Gzy
```

Do you know how can I parallelize it? You should note that the two loops are not symmetric.

Edit one: A numpythonic solution was presented above and I made a comparison between the c++ implementation, my loop version in python and thr numpythonic. Results are the following:
- c++ = 0.14seg
- numpythonic version = 1.39seg
- python loop version = 46.56seg
Probably results can get better if we use the intel version of numpy.

Comment: Your issue is not really parallelisation, it is vectorization: in numpy you should never use `for i in range(N): arr[i]=1` the right way is `arr[:]=1` . Side question Is there a particular reason you don't use a N,N,3,3 shape for your tensor instead of that N*3,N*3 one ?

Comment: I'm a c++ coder, so probably that is the reason of the mistake. The second question is not clear to me. In the end I need a 3*N x 3*N matrix (for mathematical reasons). Is it possible to convert a N, N, 3, 3 into a 3*N,3*N tensor?

Comment: To clarify: I said that because, to me, tensors are usually N-dimensionnal objects so it is only natural to use N-dim arrays to represent them. Then yes it is absolutly possible to convert to 3*N,3*N; some examples in pseudo code : Using an array (N,3,N,3) `arr[i, x_i, j, x_j].reshape(N*3,N*3)` is equivalent to your `arr[3*i+x_i, 3*j+x_j]` . An array (N,N,3,3) has to be transposed to (N,3,N,3) before the reshaping can happend `arr[i, j, x_i, x_j].transpose([0,2,1,3]).reshape(N*3,N*3)`.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarks ! And I just found a trivial modification that doubles the speed of the 'numpythonic' one : changing `np.mgrid` by `np.ogrid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is not a fast language. Number crunching with python should always use for time critical parts code written in a compiled language. With compilation down to the CPU level you can speed up the code by a factor up to 100 and then still go for parallelization. So I would not look down to using more cores doing inefficient stuff, but to work more efficient. I see the following ways to speed up the code:

1) Better use of numpy: Can you do your calculations instead on scalar level directly on vector/matrix level? eg. rx = positions[:,0]-positions[0,:] (not checked if that is correct) but something along those lines.

If that is not possible with your kind of calculations, than you can go for option 2 or 3

2) Use cython. Cython compiles Python code to C, which is then compiled to your CPU. By using static typing at the right places you can make your code much faster, see cython tutorials eg.: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/cythonize.html

3) If you are familiar with FORTRAN, it might be a good idea to write just this part in FORTRAN and then call it from Python using f2py. In fact, your code looks a lot like FORTRAN anyway. For C and C++ SWIG is one great tool to make compiled code available in Python, but there are plenty of other techniques (cython, Boost::Python, ctypes, numba etc.)

When you have done this, and it is still to slow, using GPU power with pyCUDA or parallelization with mpi4py or multiprocessing might be an option.

Comment: I'm a c++ coder and I have this code in c++, also parallelized with openmp. The code in c++ takes somehting like 0.05s to load the tensor; In python, I must wait 32s. I will accept your advise and I will try python.

Comment: I am using both, Python and C++ together. With SWIG (or other wrapper generators) it is quite easy to use your C++ code from Python.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proposition that **should now work (I corrected a few mistakes)** but that nonetheless sould give you the general idea of how verctorization can be applied to your code in order to make efficient use of numpy arrays. Everything is build in "one-pass" (ie without any for-loops) which is the *"numpythonic"* way:

```
import numpy as np
import math
N=2
k,alpha=1,1
G = np.zeros((N,3,N,3),dtype=complex)

# np.mgrid gives convenient arrays of indices that 
# can be used to write readable code
i,x_i,j,x_j = np.ogrid[0:N,0:3,0:N,0:3]
# A quick demo on how we can make the identity tensor with it
G[np.where((i == j) & (x_i == x_j))] = 1
#print(G.reshape(N*3,N*3))

positions=np.random.rand(N,3)
# Here I assumed position has shape [N,3] 
# I build arr[i,j]=position[i] - position[j] using broadcasting 
# by turning position into a column and a row 
R = np.linalg.norm(positions[None,:,:]-positions[:,None,:],axis=-1)
# R is now a N,N matrix of all the distances
#we reshape R to N,1,N,1 so that it can be broadcated to N,3,N,3 
R=R.reshape(N,1,N,1)

r=positions[None,:,:]-positions[:,None,:]

krq = (k*R)**2
pf = -k**2*alpha*np.exp(1j*k*R)/(4*math.pi*R)
a = 1.+(1j*k*R-1.)/(krq)
b = (3.-3.*1j*k*R-krq)/(krq)

#print(np.isnan(pf[:,0,:,0]))

# here we build all the combination rx*rx rx*ry etc...
comb_r=(r[:,:,:,None]*r[:,:,None,:]).transpose([0,2,1,3])
#we compute G without the pf*A term
G = pf*(b * comb_r/(R**2))
#we add pf*a term where it is due
G[np.where(x_i == x_j)] = (G + pf*a)[np.where(x_i == x_j)]
# we didn't bother with the identity or condition i!=j so we enforce it here
G[np.where(i == j)] = 0
G[np.where((i == j) & (x_i == x_j))] = 1

print(G.reshape(N*3,N*3))
```

Comment: That's exactly whaI was searching for. I will try to "read it" because there is some bug.

Comment: @NunodeSousa I fixed a few misktakes (see the edit history) in the code, it seems to be working properly now.

Comment: @NunodeSousa Additionaly, if it does work for you, it would be nice to see timing comparison with your C++ code to know how numpy efficiency fares in that case.

Comment: After a comparison between the first code, c++ and python in the same machine, the results are the following:
c++ = 0.14seg;
numpythonic version = 1.39seg;
python loop version = 46.56seg;
Probably results can get better if we use the intel version of numpy.

Comment: Since jadsq did the work I have avoided in my answer, it would be nice to mark this as the answer. A good tailored C++ version will always be faster, because you can avoid memory allocation. If you want the full power I recommend calling the C++ code from Python, which is more work.